# What is the best way to add an application to Windows Start up?

Tags: c#, .net, startup

The code i'm using in my program is the below :

```
        public static void SetStartup(string AppName, bool enable, string newpath)
    {
        if (Autostart == true)
        {
            string runKey = "SOFTWARE\\Microsoft\\Windows\\CurrentVersion\\Run";

            Microsoft.Win32.RegistryKey startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey);

            if (enable)
            {
                if (startupKey.GetValue(AppName) == null)
                {
                    startupKey.Close();
                    startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
                    // Add startup reg key
                    startupKey.SetValue(AppName, newpath);
                    startupKey.Close();
                }
            }
            else
            {
                // remove startup
                startupKey = Microsoft.Win32.Registry.LocalMachine.OpenSubKey(runKey, true);
                startupKey.DeleteValue(AppName, false);
                startupKey.Close();
            }
        }
    }
```

But When i click on the apply button, the AVG Antivirus Popup fire-up and says that my Program is a unknown Malware !?

[image]

I tried to copy my program to the StartUp folder instead, but the copied file become Limited ( must Run as administrator ), that doesn't work.

How could this be ? if it is impossible to use the function above, then how other Programs such as uTorrent start used to start automatically on each windows startup.

How can i add an option on my Program which let me make it autostart on windows start up without getting this annoying antivirus popup?

Comment: Sounds like you simply need to Allow the file to work.

Comment: The easiest way would be to copy the exe or a shortcut into the startup folder.

Comment: @Tejs The file is working, but only when i select the option Start with windows startup to ON, then i click apply, this window appears..

Comment: This sounds like it's an issue with your antivirus program, not your actual program. You probably need to get into AVG and tell it to ignore your specfic executable / location.

Comment: It might help if you signed your application. AVG might trust it then.

Answer (score -1):

If you don't want to get this annoying antivirus popup, you should simply click on the button "Allow" in the AVG window/popup.